# Coordinate geometry. Tangents and their points of contact with a circle

Tags: circles, coordinate-systems

$ S_1 \equiv x^2 + y^2 -4x+6y -23 = 0$ 
$ S_2 \equiv x^2 + y^2 -4x+6y -59 = 0 $ 
Are two circles. 
$P(8,-9)$ is a point in $S_2$. The tangents are drawn from $P$ to $S_1$ and the points of contact are $M$ and $N$. If the length of the line segment $MN$ is $x$, obtain $x^2$$-$ $70$

[image: CMPN]

Comment: Please provide more context. What have you already tried yourself? For starters, you probably should convert the equations of the circle to a standard form by completing the squares, in order to see their centers and radii.

Comment: The circles are concentric.  The radii have been carfully chosen to make it easy to find the points of tangency.

Comment: I got the answer. It's 2. The figure CMPN. Where C is the center of the circles comes out to be a square of side 6